# FileNotFound exception error even thought the file exists in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file-handling, java-io

While running my java file io program I'm getting FileNotFoundException

I tried changing the directory of the file and most of the other solution mentioned in SO, nothing works.

My code:

```
package com.HelloWorld;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileWriter w=null;
    BufferedWriter bw=null;
    try {
        String s="welcome";
        String b="‪‪D:\\test.txt";
        w=new FileWriter(b);
        bw=new BufferedWriter(w);
        bw.write(s);
        bw.flush();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("exception caught"+e);
    }
    finally{
        try {
            if(bw!=null)
                bw.close();}
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("exception caught"+e);
            }
            try {
                if(w!=null)
                {
                    w.close();
                    System.out.println("success");
                }}
                catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("exception caught"+e);
                } 
            }



}
}
```

Comment: Do you actually have a drive D:, one that you have permission to write to the root of? Have you tried using `"D:/test.txt"` instead?

Comment: Reading and writing from and to a file can be blocked by your OS depending on the file's permission attributes.

Comment: Yes I do have a drive D: but when I tried "D:/test.txt" the program runs but it does not write to the file

Comment: try wrapping b into a File object - new File(b) - and take a look at the various method the api provides. From there you should be able to figure out whether the file exists and can be written.

Answer (score 0):

I had already created the file in the D drive so the FileWriter overrides the already created file name because of which it did not write to the file